# Standalone Tomcat Server for webapp

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, web-applications

I am newbie in configuration. I have made Spring web application. When I run it on Intellij's Tomcat it works correctly. Now I would like to move to a different computer without Java, IntelliJ on it. Is it possible to do this only with Tomcat (XAMPP) installed?

Comment: no tomcat is under java ,you should install java ,then export war file from intellij and deploy in tomcat webapps dir

Answer (score 1):

To run a java web app (including Tomcat) you need to have Java on all computers at the level of your web application code.
i.e. if your web app is done with Java 1.8 then you have to have it there.

You treat the deployment as a standard java web application deployment check out this link:
http://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/how-to-deploy-a-java-web-application-on-tomcat

Comment: So there is no options to run it without java? The problem is with disk memory limitation. Java takes 200 MBs.
P.S. 
Is tomcat a good choice? I can migrate to a different eg. JBoss or something else.

Comment: Just checked it and its still working, check again or check your firewall settings